# Google cloud endpoints (app engine) + oauth2 integration with android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to integrate google app engine cloud endpoints API with android.

I have followed this links for the same:

1. [unable to connect to my google endpoints with my service object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544723/unable-to-connect-to-my-google-endpoints-with-my-service-object)
2. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android
3. [Java based Google App Engine, Android and authentication oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827919/java-based-google-app-engine-android-and-authentication-oauth2)

Here is my android app side code and app engine endpoints code:

```
**<Main activity>**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Profile profile = new Profile();
    profile.setDisplayName("Alex roger");
    profile.setAge(49l);
    new EndpointsAsyncTask(this).execute(profile);
} 

**<EndpointAsyncTask>**

public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Profile, Void, Profile> {
private MyApi myApiService;
private Context context;
SharedPreferences settings;
GoogleAccountCredential credential;
private static final String PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME = "PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME";

public EndpointsAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Profile doInBackground(Profile... params) {
    Profile profile = params[0];
    try {
            settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(context,
                "server:client_id:<web-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com");
            credential.setSelectedAccountName("<myemail_logged_in>@gmail.com");

            MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), credential);
            builder.setApplicationName(context.getPackageName());
            builder.setRootUrl("https://<my-app-id>.appspot.com/_ah/api/");
            myApiService = builder.build();

            return myApiService.saveProfile(profile.getAge(), profile.getDisplayName()).execute();

     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", String.valueOf(e.getCause() +" " +e));
    } 
     catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", e+"");
    }
    return profile;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Profile result) {
    Log.e("Display Name", result.getDisplayName());
}

}

**<MyEndpoint>**

 @Api(
    name = "myApi",
    version = "v1",
    namespace = @ApiNamespace(
            ownerDomain = "backend.endpoint",
            ownerName = "backend.endpoint",
            packagePath = ""
    ),
    scopes = {Constant.API_EMAIL_SCOPE},
    clientIds = {"<web-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            "<android-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
    audiences = {"<web-client-id>.apps.googleusercontent.com"}
)
public class MyEndpoint {


@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile",path = "saveProfile", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public Profile saveProfile(@Named("name") String name, @Named("age") long age, User user) {
    Profile profile = new Profile(name,age);
    ofy().save().entity(profile).now();

    return profile;
}

@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile1",path = "saveProfile1", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
public Profile saveProfile1(@Named("name") String name, @Named("age") long age) {
    Profile profile = new Profile(name,age);
    ofy().save().entity(profile).now();

    return profile;
}
}

**<Profile.class>**

@Entity
@Cache
public class Profile {

String displayName;
@Id
long age;

private Profile(){}
public Profile(final String displayName,final long age){
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.age = age;
}
public String getDisplayName()
{
    return displayName;
}
public  long getAge()
{
    return age;
}

}

**<OfyService>**

public class OfyService {

static {
    factory().register(Profile.class);
}

public static Objectify ofy() {
    return ObjectifyService.ofy();
}

public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
    return ObjectifyService.factory();
}
}
```

But getting error "IOException: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException".

If we don't use oAuth2 service (User user) then it is working correct. Also suggest some useful links.

Comment: Problem resolved: Was using wrong SHA1 to create android-client-id.

Comment: This link helped me to identify my error: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926709/google-endpoints-android-googleauthioexception-tic-tac-toe-removed-clientids" Note: debug.keystore file can be found in c:\Users\.android\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved: Was using wrong SHA1 to create android-client-id.
This link helped me to identify my error:

"[Google Endpoints - Android GoogleAuthIOException Tic Tac Toe - Removed clientIds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926709/google-endpoints-android-googleauthioexception-tic-tac-toe-removed-clientids)"

Note: debug.keystore file can be found in c:\Users\ .android\

Comment: ended up here after you left an 'answer' on my question ;) Glad you figured it out! just accept your answer as the correct one here. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for viewing my post. I am new to the platform thats why :P.